# How do I add a validator to ALL inputs in angular?

Tags: angular, validation, input

I have angular aplication. I want to add validation to all 255 character inputs. I use reactive forms. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: 1. What validation? 2. Is this just in one component or across many?

Comment: Do you want to apply a graphical validation ? Like applying a red background-color to all invalid inputs ? If so, you can play with angular automaticaly added classes like .ng-invalid etc.. More info there https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControlStatus

Comment: @NicholasK 1. 255 character limit 2. entry in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution to get a customize behaviour in components as input is create your own input or a directive with a custom behaviour. To do this check ngControl valueAccessor.